# Pthreads - main thread and other thread

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

In Pthreads, when we create multiple threads inside the main function, does all the created threads become a worker thread for the main thread? or each thread is a manager thread by itself?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by worker thread in context of C. can you elaborate please?

Comment: All threads are nearly equal. The only differences is that if you exit (return from) the main thread, it terminates the process (all other threads are terminated). Other than that, threads are what you make of them with your code in the threads.

Comment: I read from a tutorial that when we create a thread, it'll create multiple threads called worker thread. Am I correct  ?

Comment: If you create a thread, one thread will be created. What "kind" of thread it is, depends on what it's doing. If it does "work", it's a worker thread. If it responds to network messages, it's a network response thread. Names like "worker thread" is not distinct, it means different things in different contexts.

Comment: So when I create 3 threads inside main, totally 4 threads will be running? 3 threads that I created + main thread?

Comment: Note: C++ has its own threading model (`std::thread`). You should probably use that rather than pthreads.

Comment: @SuryaNarayanan yes.  The only obvious difference is that the 'main' thread was ceated by the OS process loader, rather than explictiy by your code.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a thread, you can call it a "worker" if you want. The thread doesn't care how people think about it. It runs the same whether you call it a "worker", "manager", or "moose" for all it matters.

Answer (score 2):

> when we create multiple threads inside the main function, does all the
>   created threads become a worker thread for the main thread?

Worker/main thread designation is conceptual.

There's no Pthreads designated thread that manages all the other worker threads. Typically, main thread is used for that job. But nothing prevents you from choosing another thread to manage all the threads. Main thread can also participate in the the "work" as a worker.

> each thread is a manager thread by itself?

A thread is an independent entity within a process. Usually, they all "co-ordinate" with each other to accomplish a common goal. But you can also have multiple groups of threads, with each group doing different tasks. So there doesn't necessarily  have to be a "manager thread". Because a thread can be completely independent  and exit (pthread_exit) without ever needing to communicate with others (e.g. Each thread sorting a separate file). Or the threads may co-ordinate with each other (e.g. matrix multiplication). Or they may be "managed" by a one thread (e.g. main thread "feeding" work to others in queue which will be worked on by other threads in a master/slaves manner).

Comment: Note: If the main thread exits. The application terminates and all other threads are killed (stone cold no unwinding of stack no checking of state etc). You should always wait for children to exit.